# While loop keeps running but not printing

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I've been searching, and nothing helped with my problem so far.
My goal is to rewrite a for loop to a while loop, and prime the while loop.
I've done this so far

```
  int i = -1;
  while (i <= 10);
  { 
     i = i + 1;
     System.out.println("i=" + i);
  }
```

The program keeps running, but doesn't print out anything.
I think it has to do with my i value, but I've tried everything I could think off T.T

Comment: Remove the semicolon on the end of the `while` line.

Comment: you loop has no body when you put a semicolon after it so no increments/ decrements  or any other operation hence infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at while end

```html
int i = -1;
  while (i <= 10)
  { 
     i = i + 1;
     System.out.println("i=" + i);
  }
```